# Bash for manipulating curly bracket delimited config files

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

Currently I have a config file of the following form:

```
under Time {
  TimeStep = 0.001;
  MaxTime = 0.2;
  MaxIts = 400;
  Type = Implicit;
  under Implicit {
    Type = ForwardEuler;
    Jacobian = FiniteDifference;
    under Newton {
      MaxIts = 20;
      Eps = 0.01;
    }
  }
}
```

First Question: I want to write a set of bash scripts that can

1. set property = value in a file; add it if it is not there.
2. get property from such a file.

line-by-line editting is not suitable here: take `MaxIts` for example, the script needs to distinguish between `Time.MaxIts` and `Time.Implicit.MaxIts`.

Second Question: I want to write a bash script that transforms above into:

```
Time.TimeStep = 0.001;
Time.MaxTime = 0.2;
Time.MaxIts = 400;
Time.Type = Implicit;
Time.Implicit.Type = ForwardEuler;
Time.Implicit.Jacobian = FiniteDifference;
Time.Implicit.Newton.MaxIts = 20;
Time.Implicit.Newton.Eps = 0.01;
```

so that sed or awk can do the job simply.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Contrary to what you seem to believe, StackOverflow isn't a free coding service. You're expected to show your code, along with relevant sample inputs, expected outputs, (which you have done),  actual error msgs as well as your comments about where you are stuck. Please show your best effort to solve this problem (use the {} tool at the top left of the edit box to format code/data/output/errMsgs correctly), and people may be able to help you. Good luck.

Comment: Also, the curly-bracket syntax you use above is not a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), therefore it is impossible to parse with regular expressions.

Comment: @dimo414: This is a partial myth. It's impossible to parse with regular expressions ALONE. However, nobody's stopping you from using multiple regular expressions and for loops to parse it. It is possible to tokenize the file using regular expressions and then process the symbolic data with a some recursive code (or a loop and an array/stack)

Comment: @slebetman sure, if you want to write a parsing library in Bash be my guest. But if that's the goal it's "Too Broad" a question for StackOverflow. At a minimum there's no pre-existing tool to parse arbitrary non-regular grammars in Bash.

Comment: @dimo414: Behold the bash JSON parser: https://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh. Notice the liberal use of awk and grep

Comment: @slebetman good for you, but the OP's example isn't JSON.

Comment: Update: I ended up using pyparsing. After specifying the grammar, it transform the file into a defaultdict. Given that input file spec is in recursive format, it seems stream editor may not be the best tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do the 2nd part:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function descend(name) {
    while ( (getline > 0) && !/}/ ) {
        if ( /{/ ) {
            descend(name "." $2)
        }
        else {
            sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"")
            print name "." $0
        }
    }
}
{ descend($2) }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Time.TimeStep = 0.001;
Time.MaxTime = 0.2;
Time.MaxIts = 400;
Time.Type = Implicit;
Time.Implicit.Type = ForwardEuler;
Time.Implicit.Jacobian = FiniteDifference;
Time.Implicit.Newton.MaxIts = 20;
Time.Implicit.Newton.Eps = 0.01;
```

I'm sure you can write a script to do the reverse mapping and then you can just do all the manipulation related to your first question on the flat format above.